# Batch file wont allow interaction until launched application has been closed

Tags: windows, batch-file, execute

I am writing a batch file that allows selections.

Here is the issue I am having...

If I select the option to launch internet Explorer in a separate window (Explorer /separate) I cannot interact with my batch file and select other options until the IE window I launched gets closed.

I want to be able to interact with my menu, launch applications, and make special selections whenever I want... I don't want to have to close the application I just launched in order to interact with my batch file again.

I am using this batch file to access different menus I have created in order to complete an array of task at different times while supporting my users (at a large IT Service Desk).

Example:

```
:MENUS1
CLS

ECHO ============= MENU NAME =============
ECHO -------------------------------------
ECHO 1.  Explorer Separate S1
ECHO 2.  Control Panel S2
ECHO 3.  Network Connections S3
ECHO 4.  Add/Remove Programs S4
ECHO 5.  Internet Options S5
ECHO 6.  Java Control Panel S6
ECHO 7.  More Options S7
ECHO -------------------------------------
ECHO 8.  Selection S8
ECHO -------------------------------------
ECHO 9.  Selection S9
ECHO -------------------------------------
ECHO ==========PRESS 'Q' TO QUIT==========
ECHO ======PRESS 'MM' FOR MAIN MENU=======
ECHO.

SET INPUT=
SET /P INPUT=Please select a number:

IF /I '%INPUT%'=='S1' GOTO SelectionS1
IF /I '%INPUT%'=='S2' GOTO SelectionS2
IF /I '%INPUT%'=='S3' GOTO SelectionS3
IF /I '%INPUT%'=='S4' GOTO SelectionS4
IF /I '%INPUT%'=='S5' GOTO SelectionS5
IF /I '%INPUT%'=='S6' GOTO SelectionS6
IF /I '%INPUT%'=='S7' GOTO SelectionS7
IF /I '%INPUT%'=='S8' GOTO SelectionS8
IF /I '%INPUT%'=='S9' GOTO SelectionS9
IF /I '%INPUT%'=='Q' GOTO Quit
IF /I '%INPUT%'=='MM' GOTO MENU

CLS

ECHO ============INVALID INPUT============
ECHO -------------------------------------
ECHO Please select a number from the 
ECHO Shortcut Menu [S1-S9] or select 'MM'
echo for Main Menu or 'Q' to quit.
ECHO -------------------------------------
ECHO ======PRESS ANY KEY TO CONTINUE======

PAUSE > NUL
GOTO MENU

REM System Shortcuts Option 1 S1

:SelectionS1
Explorer /separate
GOTO MENUS1

:SelectionS2
panel
GOTO MENUS1

:SelectionS3
ncpa.cpl
GOTO MENUS1

:SelectionS4
appwiz.cpl
GOTO MENUS1

:SelectionS5
inetcpl.cpl
GOTO MENUS1

:SelectionS6
jpicpl32.cpl
GOTO MENUS1
```

So, if I choose Option #1 - Explorer Separate S1 it executes the command explorer /separate and a new explorer window launches but if I also want to choose Option #2 - Control Panel S2 to open the Control Panel... I can't do that until I close the explorer window that the batch opened. Side note, I had to add the 'GOTO MENUS1' after each command because 1) Before I did it -- all of the commands were trying to launch one after another and 2) I want to redirect back to the menu...

Any ideas on how I can fix this to where I can interact with the batch file without having to close the applications that I have opened via the batch?

Answer (score 1):

If you want control to be returned back to the batch file before the program it launched has terminated, then you have to use `start ProgramName Options`.  For instance:

```
:SelectionS1
start Explorer /separate
GOTO MENUS1
```

The `/separate` parameter tells Windows to start a new instance of Explorer, which is different than using `start Explorer`.

Comment: Alright, I will try this and post an update tomorrow. Thanks!!